# How to extend angular-cli via a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, typescript, ember-cli, build-tools, angular-cli

I want to extend angular-cli via a custom plugin. I want to write this plugin by myself. How can i do this? If i write an ember-cli plugin, can i use this one in angular-cli? I read that not all ember-cli plugins are working in angular-cli. I would like to have an example, or some information about the architecture of angular-cli.